# What "wired connection" settings do I need to access my access point's setup page?

Tags: networking

I have a Tenda W150M which has a number of functions but I use it as an access point.

Normally, I use `Microsoft Windows` and a LAN cable to access the setup page at `192.168.2.1` but I don't have that computer available now.

I am trying to access the setup page at `192.168.2.1` with Ubuntu.  What "wired connection" settings do I need to do this?

**Edits follow:**

As far as I know, my Ubuntu 12.04 is stock.  I don't mess with comm. configs generally.  I recall that sometimes `Windows 7` with `Internet Explorer` gets to `192.168.2.1` with a stock config but I've also experienced one occasion where I had to tweak a stock `Windows 7` a bit but I don't remember what the tweak was.

Issuing this command `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

produces this output:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Issuing this command:
`ifconfig; route -n`

produces this output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:03:9a:08:d7:9b  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea03:9aff:fe08:d79b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:81012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:84117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:92583272 (92.5 MB)  TX bytes:10290944 (10.2 MB)
          Interrupt:50 Base address:0xe000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:11244 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11244 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1040726 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1040726 (1.0 MB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

The config listed here works in that the telco's DSL modem LAN drop allows Ubuntu to access the internet.  The same config will not work when the LAN cable goes to the Tenda W150M using Chrome to browse `192.168.2.1`.

If it's not obvious: the intention is to use the telco's DSL modem LAN drop to broadcast WiFi because the wireless signal from the telco's DSL modem is weak at my preferred location.

**Edit**

I found the solution for `Windows 7`, as a `YouTube` video, but I don't know how to do this in Ubuntu.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKd9zHlwhMY

Warning: the video is more than 5 minutes long!

Comment: Manually assign an IP address in the same network/subnet. e.g. 192.168.2.10. Subnet mask is most likely /32. Do it via NetworkManager or manually edit /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: you have a local ip and what to access a router on another local ip?! Why not go to a browser and enter the local ip of the router?

Comment: Of course I'm using a browser.  The output listed above are the settings used as I access this website via a drop from a DSL modem from the telco.  Without changes to the config, I physically disconnect the DSL modem and physically connect the Tenda W150M, and browse to 192.168.2.1 and it fails.  Intetion: to config the Tenda W150M to do WiFi from the drop from the telco DSL modem.

Answer (score 0):

Your results show that your Netmask is set to 255.255.255.0 and your IP address is 192.168.1.100

This means that you computer will talk directly to devices with IP address 192.168.0.x where x is 0 to 254

Your settings are being set up via DHCP and that DHCP server is probably in the device located at 192.168.1.1

Are you sure the address you want is 192.168.2.1 and not 192.168.1.1?  If you are then you can temporarily change the Netmask with this command

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

and you should be able to connect.  Source [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

This change will only last until you reboot at which point it will take the settings from `/etc/network/interfaces` again.

If you want to make this permanent then edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to set static IP, Netmask and default gateway. As described in the link given.

If you do decide to set a static address make sure your DHCP server is set so the static addresses and dynamically assigned ones do not overlap.

On my home network I have

```
IP 192.168.0.1 - My router (Static IP)
IP 192.168.0.2   to 192.168.0.199 - DHCP Assigned: Computers, PS3, Smart phones, etc.
IP 192.168.0.200 to 192.168.0.254 - Statc Assigned: Printers and NAS
```

Comment: Yes, the device is at 192.168.2.1 because that is on the label on the device.  Also the Youtube video that I reference is using that address.  About your solution: if you recommend a temporary change, then how is it temporary?  Will these changes revert on a reboot?  If not then how is it temporary?

Comment: Your solution did not work.  It failed to connected via the wired connection.

Comment: Just tested here. Two routers one at `192.168.0.1` with DHCP enabled. Another with `192.168.1.1` DHCP switched off.  Reboot PC I get `IP 192.168.0.2` `Netmask 255.255.255.0` `DefGW 192.168.0.1`.  I can connect to router at `192.168.0.1` but not `192.168.1.1` I run  `sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.0.0` and I can connect to both routers.  This suggests the IP address you have is wrong.  Note the default IP can be changed.

Comment: Running the command `sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.0.0` changes netmask it was `255.255.255.0` so my PC could only directly connect to devices in the range `192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.254` initially after running the command I netmask changed to `255.255.0.0` and I could connect to devices in the range `192.168.1.0 to 192.168.255.254`

Comment: Assign `192.168.1.100` to eth0 will **NOT** help because it is still in 192.168.1.0/32 network, won't be able to reach `192.168.2.1` which is in a different network, due to the bridge connection there is no router to `192.168.2.0/32`, see my reply for details.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `/24` instead of `/32`.

Answer (score 0):

**Networking Basics**

As mentioned earlier in the comment, to access`192.168.2.1` which is on a different network, **you need a router**, if **NOT**, you have to change `eth0` interface and assign it an IP which is within `192.168.2.0/24` network, it is equivalent to `192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0`.

According to you output, `eth0` interface has IP `192.168.1.100`, most likely assigned by 1st level router's DHCP service.

Looking at the routing table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

`192.168.1.1` is your default gateway, there is no route to 192.168.2.0/24 because they are 2 different networks and the 1st level router is NOT connected with you Tenda W150M anyway.

**Simple workaround**
Set your `eth0` interface, assign an IP address in 192.168.2.0/32 manually.

For example: `ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.10 netmask 255.255.255.0`

If it is connected directly to Tenda W150M, you should be able to ping 192.168.2.1 and access the web console.

BTW: You don't have eth0 entry in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Unless you set it manually, otherwise it is weird.

Comment: Its not a /32 Network. If it were the Netmask would be `255.255.255.255`.  See [here](http://www.ripe.net/internet-coordination/press-centre/understanding-ip-addressing).  What you have defined with your `ifconfig` command is a /24 Network and should be able access devices in the range `192.168.2.0 to 192.168.2.255`  My `ifconfig` defined a /16 Network and should be able access devices in the range `192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255`. Either can ping `192.168.2.1` if there is a device there

Comment: Sorry, typo, 255.255.255.0 => CIDR form is `/24`. Somehow 32 came up in my mind when I was typing. I understand what you are saying, you are using a `/16` mask which makes more IP addresses for the network availabe. Mine is only a simple workaround as mentioned.